# Python multithreading radial basis function

Tags: python, multithreading, artificial-intelligence, multiprocessing

So i need to make an Radial Basis Function run a bit quicker

```
    while(error):
        epoch += 1
        error = 0
        for i in xrange(self.numPoints):
            dp = self.dotProduct(g[i], self.weights)
            signum = self.sig(dp)
            if dp < 0 and g[i].classification == 1:
                self.updateWeights(signum, g[i])
                error += 1
            elif dp > 0 and g[i].classification == -1:
                self.updateWeights(signum, g[i])
                error += 1
            elif dp == 0:
                self.updateWeights(signum, g[i])
                error += 1
        if epoch > 10000:
            return 0
    print "Epochs %i, %i Dimensions" % (epoch, self.numWeights - 1)
    return 1

def dotProduct(self, x, y):
    ret = 0.0
    for i in xrange(len(y)):
        ret += x.points[i]*y[i]
    return ret

def sig(self, x):
    if x < 0:
        return 1
    if x > 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

def updateWeights(self, s, g):
    for i in xrange(self.numWeights):
        self.weights[i] = self.weights[i] + self.learningRate * s * g.points[i]
```

I was wanting to use concurrent threads but python threading locks threads until the previous thread has finished so it will not make it any faster that running a single main thread.

I need to find a way to run threads concurrently, a single thread for every:
   for i in xrange(self.numPoints):
But locking the values for self.weights, meaning that only one thread can change them at a time.

Anyone got any ideas how this can be done?

This works great on a small data set but when using real data gets a little hairy

Answer (score 2):

You could use numpy arrays to improve performance e.g.:

```
import numpy as np

def dotProduct(self, x, y):
    return np.dot(x.point, y)

def updateWeights(self, s, g):
    self.weights += self.learningRate * s * g.points
```

where `x.point`, `y`, `self.weights`, `g.points` are 1d numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Python multihreading run all threads in a singe process on one CPU core.

To run truly parallel thread you should use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library.

Comment: Why was this voted down? I'm not an expert in the area and so didn't answer, but based upon what knowledge I have, I too thought this was the correct answer. I can at the very least confirm that using the threading module in Python for calculation-based stuff hurts performance compared to just executing things sequentially in a single thread. If the downvoter thinks this answer is wrong, why doesn't he come and explain why?